# Is it possible to serialize an xarray DataArray which holds lazy dask-array data pointing to a file?

Tags: python, serialization, deserialization, dask, python-xarray

I have built up a huge dask array from multiple source hdf5 files.

Let's assume, data comes from one hdf5 file only:

```py
import dask.array as da
import h5py
import xarray as xr

h5_data = h5py.File(path_to_file, "r")
dask_arr = da.from_array(h5_data, chunks=chunksize)
```

Then I arranged (lazy) slices from that dask array into an xarray Dataset

```py
xr_data = xr.DataArray(dask_arr[0:1000])
# Note: In reality, xr_data and dask[0:1000] aggregation is much more complex and needs quite long to process
```

Now I want to serialize the xr_data object, so I do not need to calcuate it every single time.

The data in the xarray DataArray is lazily mapped via dask to to hdf5 file.
How can I serialize (pickle? netcdf? ...) to be able to reload the xarray object while the "lazy mapping" persists?

Thank you out there!

Answer (score 2):

In general you should be able to do this.  Both Dask and Xarray objects are picklable.  This will serialize the graph into bytes that you could then write into a file.

However, in your particular case, this graph contains h5py.Dataset objects, which unfortunately are not serializable.

The xarray `open_dataset` methods get around this in various ways.  If you can use them along with various `concat` calls then I think that that's probably your best bet, rather than using `h5py.Dataset` objects directly.

Comment: Thanks for your input! Unfortunately in my current usecase, I cannot use xarray's open_dataset directly. In a first "data-read-layer" I use pure dask arrays.
Then, after some index calculations I slice the dask arrays and fill an xarray, which I then want to serialize to prevent the need of doing the index calculations all over again.

Comment: Does it make sense to investigate, if h5py.Dataset objects can be serialized in any way?

Comment: If you check the h5py issue tracker you will find an issue that is several years old.  I recommend asking there.

Comment: The module h5pickle made it work to pickle "h5py data", also lazily wrapped in a dask array. When pickling the dask array itself, really only the definition is pickled (no data). But when this dask array is wrapped by an xarray, serializing that xarray leads to a huge pickle file holding the data too. How can I tell xarray, not to load the data when serializing?